# d'Hondt method inverse calculator

Tags: r, dirichlet

I've found this code from Carlos Gil Bellosta for seats distribution in electoral systems with d'Hondt method.

```
# d'Hondt scores and counts
dHondt <- function(candidates, votes, seats){ 
  tmp <- data.frame( 
    candidates = rep( candidates, each = seats ), 
    scores     = as.vector(sapply( votes, function(x) x / 1:seats )) 
  ) 
  tmp <- tmp$candidates[order( - tmp$scores )] [1:seats]
  tmp <- as.data.frame(table(tmp)) [ ,2]
  return (tmp)
}
```

Now I'm wondering how to reverse this function, that is, estimate vote percentages for n parties starting from their seats.

Obvously this requires a probabilistic aproach. I tried to simulate lots of possibly results and found their seats equivalence, building something similar to a probability table. Solution? Find the nearest n-tuple(s) for the seat distribution I'm interested in. Looks so old-fashioned, I know. This is my code.

```
# sample results
generate <- function(distribution, threshold) {
  repeat {
    y <- rgamma(length(distribution), distribution, 1)
    if (all(y / sum(y) >= rep(threshold, length(distribution)))) {
      return (y/sum(y))
      break
    }
  }
}

# parameters
lookup <- c(7,6,3,2,2)
seats <- sum(lookup)
parties <- length(lookup)
names <- letters[1:parties]
threshold <- .05
sample <- 1E5 # there must be enough generated combinations for 6-7 parties gaining representation and parliaments up to 150 seats

# concentration parameters / priors for uniform dirichlet
priors <- rep(1, parties)
# priors <- c(7,6,3,2,2)   # change for a more concentrated random distribution near the relative values derived from these numbers

# percentages (base: votes for candidates over threshold)
p <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=sample, ncol=parties)
for(j in 1:sample){
  p[j, ] <- generate(priors, threshold)
  p[j, ] <- sort(p[j, ], decreasing = T)
}
p <- data.frame(p)
colnames(p) <- names

# seats
s <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=sample, ncol=parties)
for(j in 1:sample){
  s[j, ] <- dHondt(names, p[j, ], seats)
}
s <- data.frame(s)
colnames(s) <- names

# reverse lookup
i <- apply(s, 1, function(x) all(x == lookup))
s[i, ]
p[i, ]
summary(p[i, ])
```

Wonder if anyone suggest this can be done in a more elegant and direct way.

Comment: Fascinating problem. I'm guessing that one of the many modern probabilistic programming languages (e.g. pymc3, stan) could be used to set this model up and run it both forwards and backwards, since that is one of their claims to fame.